# upload_max_filesize set to 4M in phpinfo(), can't change it!

Tags: file, file-upload, php

I've got this in my php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 25M
post_max_size = 25M
```

and I've got this in my .htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 26214400
php_value post_max_size 26214400
```

as shorthand can only be used in the php.ini (http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes)

but no matter what I do, when i call `phpinfo()` I get

```
Directive               Local Value     Master Value
upload_max_filesize     4M              25M
```

I've looked at all other php.ini files, my .htaccess, ini_set(). Anything I could think of and nothing will change it from 4M. Any help would be great!

EDIT: restarting apache didn't work, i've check my httpd.conf, it seems like an external file or something. any other places to check?

Comment: For Archive purpose: If you have an error in your php.ini the next lines will not parsed, so the value you are setting will not load.

Comment: If you change this value through cPanel, it might change the local value. It worked for me, I just clicked save because the value was actually loaded from php.ini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was it was actually being set in another .ini file that didn't appear at first glance to be related to anything!

Note to self: always use "grep" to search within files when things are fishy!

Comment: What file was it?  I've checked every php.ini, .htaccess, and all of the files listed under "additional .ini files parsed" and still have this issue.

Answer (score 6):

That doesn't look like proper syntax for a php.ini file.

```
upload_max_filesize = 25M
post_max_size = 25M
```

Then, make sure to restart Apache.

If you still have troubles, refer to:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Comment: Also, you can check the run-time configuration options by calling ini_get('upload_max_filesize'). I find it more convenient than phpinfoing.

Comment: woops! that's a typo in the question, I have the equals operator in the actual file. I fixed the post.

Comment: @ Zach Rattner i use that in the script as well, but still only gives me 4M

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue, but restarting php-fpm helped.
So it didn't help to restart just apache2, but this command:

```sh
sudo systemctl restart php7.3-fpm
```

Cleared probably some cache and took the new modified `php.ini`.

Comment: Solved my identical problem. Only I had to restart php-fpm, wasn't versioned php service..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OSX then make sure your php.ini file is not the default one in /etc (php.ini.default) with the command `php --ini`,
output sample :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

in case the first line: Configuration File (php.ini) Path with empty parameter make a copy of the default php ini and the changes will take affect.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're editing the `php.ini` in the `conf/"server_version"` folder

Answer (score 0):

also, you'll have to check the memory_limit directive.

If it's lower than upload_max_filesize or post_max_size then their value will be limited to the memory_limit value.

Anyway, post_max_size should be slightly larger than upload_max_filesize (any posted values other than the file itself would need some memory as well)

On modern systems, memory_limit should be at least 64M, 128M or more is recommended

Comment: I have memory limit at 64M, I could bump that up to 128. But still, post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are both 25M, which I'll make post_max_size a little larger. Still, I just don't know why 4M won't change.

Comment: depending on your web server construction, you may have more than one php.ini files on your server. It is highly likely, that you have edited the wrong one. Try to find one in your /etc/apache2, /etc/httpd, /etc/php5, /etc/php, there may be one somewhere in the /usr/something-related-to-php folders

If you are using some web server automation software, such as cpanel, ispconfig or something similar, you should check the account in question for custom php.ini settings, as they will override what you did in your main phyp.ini file(s)

Comment: right, i've done a search, but i'll keep checking if there are any php.ini's i've missed, i'll comment again when i've done an even more thorough search for these. I've found 5 so far, but maybe there are more.

Comment: @mlebrun15: when you're done hold give me a list about these file with their path, i may be able to tell you which one is the boss.

Comment: /etc/php.ini --
/etc/php.ini.bu --
/etc/php.ini.rpmnew --
/home/rack/100402-02049/php.ini --
/opt/hp/hpsmh/bin/php.ini

Comment: that command gave you all those files, there are no more.

`/etc/php.ini` is the main php ini file.
`/home/rack/100402-02049/php.ini` if you have your web stuff running through a user the `rack` then this is the culprit
`/opt/hp/hpsmh/bin/php.ini` this seems to be one for a printer driver?
Edit the first two. The other files with different extensions are not used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PHP Fast cgi then you need to restart the process. I believe that restarting apache should do the trick.

Comment: it still tells me that the "Local Value" is 4M in phpinfo(). My master value changes with whatever i set the php.ini to but the local value always says 4M.

Comment: There is probably another .htaccess altering this then. Perhaps the apache core config is even overwriting this.

Comment: another .htaccess? can't there only be one in a folder? and if there was another one in a different folder that wouldn't mess with it would it?

Comment: If .htaccess files are enabled, then apache checks each folder on down starting with the apache server config, then web root, then any sub directories, etc. While their can only be one per folder, there can be many folders sometimes that overwrite each other. Personally, I would disable .htaccess files and edit the core apache vhost config with the settings you want and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I can't disable .htaccess due to certain security reasons, but i'll look into that hierarchy and comment back here with any findings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a local server, such as wamp or xampp, make sure it's using the php.ini you think it is.  These servers usually default to a php.ini that's not in your html docs folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WAMP then make changes in proper php.ini which apache uses, normally its found in C:\wamp\bin\apache\\bin.

make changes in 2 parameters post_max_size and upload_max_filesize (found in line 734 and 886, usually),  to 50M (to upload files upto 50 MB).

don't forget to restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem via a workaround. I created .user.ini file in the root document of my webapp and overwrite the values.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.
Check Loaded Configuration File path in php info.
Then open that file and change the variables you want and restart your apache server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cPanel/WHM, use MultiPHP INI Editor to update in cPanel (Local Value) and WHM (Master Value) >> Restart Apache or other web server.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that your computer is not hiding a `.txt` on the end of the `php.ini` file.

Use terminal or right click / get info or properties.